# Sveltekit component doesn't update filtered object on pagination

Tags: reactive-programming, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

I'm new to Svelte and struggling with the reactive nature of passing variables to a component.

I have:

- votes = json object holding all votes for all actors
- /actors = paginated display of pages with variables passed to URL via goto (i.e. /actors?page=0&limit=10)

In actors/+page.svelte I have a loop which passes in a single actor's vote from a json object of all the actors' votes:

```
{#each data.actors as actor}
       <Person actor={actor} vote={votes.length ? votes.filter(function (entry) {
            if(entry.type === 'actor' && entry.typeId === actor.id){
                  return true;
            }
            return false;
            }):{}} hasSession={!!data.session}/>
{/each}
```

And the component Person.svelte does some logic to calculate:

```
    export let actor;
    export let vote; //the vote json object (if exists)
   
    let voted = vote.length ? true : false;
    let lastVote = vote.length && typeof(vote[0].vote) ? vote[0].vote :  false; 
    
    let voteAvg = actor.voteAvg;
    let voteTotal = actor.voteTotal;
    
    
    let captureVote = async function(e){
        
        const newVote = e.target.value;
        
        //update the card
        voteAvg = voteAvg - lastVote + parseInt(newVote);
        
        const response = await fetch('/vote', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({ 
                type:'actor',
                actorId: actor.id, 
                vote:newVote,
                lastVote:lastVote,
                voted:voted
            }),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });
        
        if( !voted ){
            console.log('fist vote');
            voteTotal++;
            voted = true;
        }
        
    }
```

with the variables being passed into the html as follows (Using Skeleton.dev components):

```
<div class="p-4 space-y-4">

        <a href="/actor/{actor.id}">
            <h4 class="h5 h-14 max-h-full overflow-hidden" data-toc-ignore="">{actor.name}</h4>
        </a>
        
        <div class="flex w-100 items-center space-x-4">
            <div class="flex-auto flex justify-between items-center">
                <span class="chip variant-filled">{voteAvg}</span>
                <small class="small">{voteTotal} votes</small>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    
    <hr class="opacity-50">
    <footer class="p-2 w-100">
        
            <RadioGroup background="none" display="flex" border="none" active="variant-filled-primary" hover="hover:variant-soft-primary">
                <RadioItem bind:group={lastVote}  on:click={captureVote} name="justify" value={1}><i class="fa-regular fa-thumbs-up"></i></RadioItem>
                <RadioItem bind:group={lastVote} on:click={captureVote} name="justify" value={-1}><i class="fa-regular fa-thumbs-down"></i></RadioItem>
                <RadioItem bind:group={lastVote}  on:click={captureVote} name="justify" value={0}><i class="fa-regular fa-minus"></i></RadioItem>
            </RadioGroup>
            
    </footer>
```

Everything works as expected as far as paginating through actors - their details update as page/limit changes - however the "vote" object being passed in remains static to the order it was passed into on the initial load. A console.log inside Person component demonstrates that it isn't firing the calculation logic again, and/or the filtering logic is not being passed in.

I tried to change the variables in Person.svelte to be reactive - i.e.

```
$: voted = vote.length ? true : false;
$: lastVote = vote.length && typeof(vote[0].vote) ? vote[0].vote :  false; 
$: voteAvg = actor.voteAvg;
$: voteTotal = actor.voteTotal;
```

while this did initially appear to solve the problem (proper votes were displaying as i paginate through results), the component's logic of casting a vote and updating things like voteAvg and voteTotal no longer worked.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong but your help is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: I would suggest taking data.actors and assuming there is data.votes that you apply the logic that you have in the template in the each loop and move that logic to a data processing function method that prepares the data.actors and attaches votes to each new actor object and you loop over that instead. This would mean every actor as its votes already to perform calcs on in Person component and you would not have ugly logic in your template.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @GotStu ! It definitely cleaned up the code in +page.svelte to move the logic of attaching a vote to an actor in the +server.js endpoint that retrieves the actors. Makes sense...  unfortunately, it's functioning exactly the same way.  Maybe you suggested to move the logic that's in Person.svelte out as well? Not sure that's doable

Comment: it looks like you are not updating the vote object and are only increasing local variables.
voteTotal++;           voted = true;. Try updating the vote objects passed in

Comment: Try adding a *key* to your `#each` loop: `{#each data.actors as actor (actor.id)}`. This should force each `Person` component to re-render whenever iterating on a new actor id, which in turn should force the `vote` prop to be evaluated again.

Comment: Thank you both - i have it working by essentially moving almost all logic from Person component to actors/+server.js 

only needed one reactive variable in Person
`$: voted = actor.vote.length ? true : false;`

thx for the tip on adding an ID to `#each` loop @ThomasHennes